# Grails restart takes long after file modification

Tags: grails

everytime I make modifications to,for example, a .gsp file in my grails app, I need to restart with:

call init prod run-app -Dserver.port=85 -Dgrails.app.context=/

Each restart is however taking quite some time (10-20seconds). How can I make modifications to files but avoid long restart times?

Comment: in the dev environment files get loaded automatically via springloaded?  why do you run as prod?

Answer (score -3):

Solved by:

call init dev run-app -Dserver.port=85 -Dgrails.app.context=/

Comment: dev is the default for run-app.  what is "call init"? and i hope you are on windows (where maybe low ports are allowed for each and every user) or this smells like either running as root or you just have started your production environment in dev mode (which both is as bad as it gets)

Comment: This line is used when doing development. So I understand "dev" is right here. Not running as root and I am on windows.